# How to output JSON from Python?

Tags: javascript, python

Using `dict.toSource()` writing `dictVar` to an external python file:

```
var dictVar = {'one':'1','two':'2'};
fileOut = new File('./out.py');    
fileOut.open("w","TEXT","????");
fileOut.write(dictVar.toSource());
fileOut.close();
```

This results to a line in out.py:

```
({one:"1", two:"2"})
```

while expecting:

```
({'one':"1", 'two':"2"})
```

Question: Is there a way to write a dictionary where its key names are written to an output file as strings (such as `'one'` and `'two'` instead of `one` and `two`)?

Comment: Sounds like you want to write JSON instead.

Comment: Try JSON.stringify(..) on the object

Comment: Unfortunately `JSON` is not available within an application running `JavaScript`. I need to accomplish it using all stock JavaScript capabilities.

Comment: Why isn't it available? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

otherwise there is a javascript implementation available for JSON: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Comment: I am getting `JSON is undefined` Error...

Comment: @Sputnix which browser?

Comment: It is not browser but Adobe application supporting `JavaScript`. I am trying to avoid dealing with `JSON` since then there will be a need to watch Json install on every machine. I am looking for a solution within `javascript`.